# notepad++ I want to do all numbers which I write have different color

Tags: colors, numbers, notepad++, notepad

I have a map of numbers. like:

```
00 00 00 09 09 09 09 00
00 00 00 09 09 09 09 00
00 00 00 09 09 09 09 00
00 00 00 09 09 09 09 00
01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 05 05 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And I want these numbers to be in different colors.
for exepmle: if the number is 05, it is gonna be red and if the number is 00, it is gonna be green.
How can I set notepad++ for that?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do such thing with Notepad++ it is a simple text editor.

Comment: I guess there is user defination language option in notepad++ and maybe I can define my own. But I don't have any idea about it.